# General method for finding the basis of the image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, image-processing

Let $f: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation, and let $\mathfrak{B}_V=\{b_i\}$ be a basis of $V$. If the images of the elements of the basis $\mathfrak{B}_V=\{b_i\}$ are $\{f(b_i)\}$, then how would the base of the image of $f$ be found?

**My attempt at a solution**

I have tried to work out a general method this way: as $f$ is a linear transformation, then, $\forall x \in V$, $f(x)=f(\lambda_1b_1+\lambda_2b_2+...+\lambda_mb_m)=\lambda_1f(b_1)+\lambda_2f(b_2)+...+\lambda_mf(b_m)$. Therefore, the image of any element in $V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors $\{f(b_i)\}$. My doubt is this: will this set be linearly independent (*i.e.*, a basis) or this is not necessarily the case (*i.e.*, a generating set)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case. For a simple example, take $V, W$ finite dimensional with positive dimensions and $f = 0$.

You can check that $f(\mathfrak{B}_V)$ is a basis of the image of $f$ if and only if $f$ is injective.

Edit: I just noticed that I didn't actually answer your question. To find a basis, just do row reduction on the matrix with the vectors of $f(\mathfrak{B}_V)$ as columns and remove linearly dependent vectors.

Edit 2: Changed $\mathfrak{B}_V$ to $f(\mathfrak{B}_V)$

Answer (score 1):

Let the basis of $\mathrm{ker}(f)\subseteq V$ be $\{v_1,v_2\cdots,v_k\}$, where $k=\dim(\mathrm{ker}(f))$. Extend this basis of $\mathrm{ker}(f)$ into a basis of the entire space $V$, let it be $\{v_1,\cdots,v_k,v_{k+1},\cdots,v_n\}$, where $n=\mathrm{dim}(V)$. Then $\{f(v_{k+1}),\cdots,f(v_n)\}$ form a basis of $\mathrm{Im}(f)\subseteq W$.

This is because $\lambda_1 f(v_{k+1})+\cdots+\lambda_{n-k}f(v_n)=0\Rightarrow f(\lambda_1v_{k+1}+\cdots+\lambda_{n-k}v_n)=0$. As $v_{k+1},\cdots,v_n\not\in\mathrm{ker}(f)$, then this can hold only if $\lambda_1v_{k+1}+\cdots+\lambda_{n-k}v_n-0$, which implies $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i=1,\cdots,n-k$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to find a basis for a set of vectors, put them as the columns of a matrix, and then row-reduce.  It's easy to read off a basis for the column space of the reduced matrix.  Now the *corresponding* columns of the original matrix form the basis you are looking for.

If you go all the way to the RREF, then a basis will be formed by the *pivot columns* (the columns which contain leading $1$'s).

Now to answer the question in the title, note that you can take the basis $\beta=\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ to be the standard basis, in case $V$ is $n$-dimensional.  You get a matrix whose columns are the $f(e_i)$.  Now recall that the image of $f$ will be the column space.  Follow the procedure outlined above, and you will have your basis.